# set crossDomain: true in angularJS http.get() method

Tags: angularjs

I have to call one ajax request using angular JS $http.get method but it shows me error

**Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://example.com. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).**

My method is

```
$http.get(url).success( function(response) {
   // some thing here
});
```

there is any way to set **crossDomain: true** in get method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are following options:

1. Use [JSONP](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#jsonp).
2. Add `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*'` on the server.
3. Use Chrome with `'--disable-web-security'` flag.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are not trying to call the get method by browsing a local html file. Try launching it via http-server and then you can even use jsonp

Answer (score -1):

You have to allow the cors:

```
.config(function($httpProvider){ 
    $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["Accept"] = "application/json";
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8';

})
```